# Jotform to Google Sheets. New Row when Google Sheets senses any change

Tags: google-sheets, automation, jotform

I'm kind of a newb at this so I'm hoping someone can help. I have a Jotform to Google Sheets automation set up where when I update an existing Jotform submission, it will update the existing Google Sheets entry. However, that means whenever I edit a current submission, it will erase the previous entry. I want to keep that entry. So I was hoping someone could help me create a code or automation that would create a new row at the top of the Google Sheet whenever it senses an update. So it keeps the previous entry and creates a new one. I hope that makes sense and I can help answer questions or include screenshots or whatever.

Thanks for your help.

Gibson

The automation currently just updates the current submission on Google Sheets thus erasing the previous entry. I want to make sure the previous entry doesn't disappear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.